# In Rust, how to get the text of TextEdit widget Slint gui

Tags: user-interface, rust, slint

I'm learning Slint (and Rust) and I'm stuck reading text attribute of TextEdit widget.

My slint gui is described as following :

```rust
import { Button, VerticalBox } from "std-widgets.slint";
import { HorizontalBox, TextEdit } from "std-widgets.slint";

export component AppWindow inherits Window {
    in-out property<int> counter: 42;
    out property<string> thetext: "Pouet";
    callback request-increase-value();
    callback compute-qr-code();
    callback qr-note-edited();
    VerticalBox {
        TextEdit {
            text: thetext;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            edited => {
                root.qr-note-edited();
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Increase value";
            clicked => {
                root.request-increase-value();
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Gen QRNote";
            clicked => {
                root.compute-qr-code();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, in the rust `main()` function I'm trying to get the text value to print it in console :

```rust
slint::include_modules!();

fn main() -> Result<(), slint::PlatformError> {
    let ui = AppWindow::new()?;

    let ui_handle = ui.as_weak();
    ui.on_request_increase_value(move || {
        let ui = ui_handle.unwrap();
        ui.set_counter(ui.get_counter() + 1);
        println!("button pushed");
    });

    let ui_handle = ui.as_weak();
    ui.on_compute_qr_code(move || {
        let ui = ui_handle.unwrap();
        println!("{}",ui.get_thetext());
    });

    let ui_handle = ui.as_weak();
    ui.on_qr_note_edited(move || {
        let ui = ui_handle.unwrap();
        println!("text changed -> {}", ui.get_thetext());
    });

    ui.run()
}
```

When I click on `Gen QRNote` button, initial text "Pouet" is displayed.
But if I modify text in gui TextEdit and re-click on `Gen QRNote`, edited text is not displayed, only the initial "Pouet" text.

It seems that ui is duplicated. What is the right method to point on initial ui reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternative 1

You need to manually update the `thetext` property when the `edited` event occurs:

```
import { Button, VerticalBox } from "std-widgets.slint";
import { HorizontalBox, TextEdit } from "std-widgets.slint";

export component AppWindow inherits Window {
    in-out property<int> counter: 42;
    out property<string> thetext: "Pouet";
    callback request-increase-value();
    callback compute-qr-code();
    callback qr-note-edited();
    VerticalBox {
        TextEdit {
            text: thetext;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            edited(text) => {
                thetext = text;
                root.qr-note-edited();
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Increase value";
            clicked => {
                root.request-increase-value();
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Gen QRNote";
            clicked => {
                root.compute-qr-code();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Alternative 2

You can make the `thetext` property `in-out` and accept a `string` argument in your `qr-note-edited` callback:

```
import { Button, VerticalBox } from "std-widgets.slint";
import { HorizontalBox, TextEdit } from "std-widgets.slint";

export component AppWindow inherits Window {
    in-out property<int> counter: 42;
    in-out property<string> thetext: "Pouet";
    callback request-increase-value();
    callback compute-qr-code();
    callback qr-note-edited(string);
    VerticalBox {
        TextEdit {
            text: thetext;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            edited(text) => {
                root.qr-note-edited(text);
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Increase value";
            clicked => {
                root.request-increase-value();
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Gen QRNote";
            clicked => {
                root.compute-qr-code();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can update the `thetext` property in your rust callback like so:

```rust
ui.on_qr_note_edited(move |new_text| {
    let ui = ui_handle.unwrap();
    ui.set_thetext(new_text);
    println!("text changed -> {}", ui.get_thetext());
});
```